# Oracle Forms auto add employees on the next row

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a table like this:

```
+------------+
|  EMP_CODE  |
+------------+
|CODEA       |
|CODEA1      |
|CODEA2      |
|CODEB       |
|CODEC       |
|CODEC2      |
|CODED       |
|CODED1      |
|CODEE       |
|CODEE1      |
|CODEE2      |
+------------+
```

My multi-row block in forms:

[image]

What I wanted is if I add for example the EMP_CODE **CODEE**, it will automatically add EMP_CODE(s) with **CODEE** on the next row and so on. Like this:

[image]

Just tell me if I missed out something or if there's something unclear on my explanation. Thank you!

Comment: How does `CODEE` relate to `CODEE1` and `CODEE2`?

Comment: they both have, let's say, the same root code **CODEE**

Comment: If it does have, then you could populate onto the read-only columns by executing a query in the `KEY_NEXT_ITEM` trigger.

Comment: it is not read-only

Comment: It doesn't have to be read-only, the rationale to mention is because `CODEE1` and `CODEE2` are automatically populated as specifies in the question.

Comment: hmmm.. I see. You may want to try to answer this question.

Comment: Will try to explain one approach, perhaps there could be other better ways to achieve the desired functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will try to explain one approach, perhaps there would be better ways to achieve the desired functionality.

The below is pseudo code, improvise and change as per your request.

```
KEY-NEXT-ITEM

BEGIN
      SELECT emp INTO :your_block_name.column_name
      FROM table_name
      WHERE column_name = :block_name.emp;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
       // consider raising or do as per logic
    END;
```

Having answered this, I believe the table design is not correct for which perhaps instigate a separate discussion to dissect.